# Tom Tom Navigation device that records driven route?

Tags: navigation

I'm looking for a Tom Tom navigation device that does not only provide routing information but that also records the route I'm driving. I would prefer a ready-made solution, but if not possible, I would also be fine with installing a mode/scripting.

Comment: Do you want one that is literally Tom Tom brand, or will any brand of navigation system do?

Answer (score 0):

Some units can output a serial NMEA0183 data stream which gives lat/long coords. These can then be superimposed on a digital map